# Value escaped with mysql_real_escape_string() before inserting into database, but stored value is not escaped

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I read in some tutorials/example that this function will save in database the

```
<a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>
```

as

```
<a href=\"http://foo.com\">foo</a>
```

In my case (i have magic_quotes off as many people suggests),

```
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);
$sql="INSERT INTO test (text) VALUES ('$text')";
```

it is saved as `<a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>` in the DB which I see through phpMyAdmin.

I guess this is because of `magic_quotes` because when I had them on, it was saved as `<a href=\"http://foo.com\">foo</a>`.

With `magic_quotes` turned off and my example above, am I safe against SQL injections?

Comment: Just use prepared statements (in PHP, that means **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**) and [fuhgeddaboudit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mCIGqhcSxtg).

Comment: More generally, SQL injection occurs at the time of running the query. If your input saved correctly, then there is nothing further to fear. The data probably *is* saved with quote escaping but the utility you're using to view the data is most likely filtering it for display.

Comment: when you need ouput any data from database parse it with [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of escaping is to make ambiguous syntax unambiguous.

```
INSERT INTO test (text) VALUES ("<a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>")
```

This is ambiguous/wrong because the database cannot tell whether the `"` inside the `"` are to be taken literally or whether they signal the end of the string you want to put in the database. Notice the screwed up syntax highlighting here on SO as well. `mysql_real_escape_string` escapes that to:

```
INSERT INTO test (text) VALUES ("<a href=\"http://foo.com\">foo</a>")
```

This is now unambiguous, the inner `"` do *not* signal the end of the string.

That's the only thing escaping does, it does not *permanently* insert backslashes into the string.

Please read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Answer (score 2):

mysql_real_escape_string will save you from sql injections on strings. It is an alternative to addslashes().  If you look at addslashes you will see that is what magic_quotes does.  It simply calls addslashes automatically on various sources of input.  mysql_real_escape_string is better for use with mysql because it is aware of the mysql character sets being used AND it escapes additional characters specific to mysql's SQL dialect.

For other datatypes, you still need to take precautions... for example, if you're passing an integer to be stored, you should cast it to int or use sprintf and the appropriate type character strings with it.

As previously stated, the best prevention is to use mysqli or pdo rather than mysql, and use bind variables. That approach is impervious across the board to sql injection.

Comment: A note on integers: You can use the intval() function to convert to int.

Comment: @Giorkouros: I think other people spelled it out, but you were definately doing the best practice in avoiding the use of magic quotes which is a deprecated feature.  If it's on, it becomes a source of spurious slashes as I think you encountered.  People that write generic scripts that have to account for it, will typically provide routines that detect if it's turned on, and go through input ($_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE etc) and run stripslashes() to negate them, then do the correct thing.

Comment: @waitinforatrain: just one of those little performance tips: but it's actually much more efficient to typecast to an int than to use intval().

Answer (score 1):

The point of using mysql_real_escape_string is to escape characters for your query, so what you see in your database is correct (otherwise when you use an SQL SELECT it would give you the string with the backslashes).

So your query looks like: `INSERT INTO test (text) VALUES ("<a href=\"http://foo.com\">foo</a>")` which inserts it into the text column as `<a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>`.

The `\` is just to tell the mysql query that you're using a `"` character instead of closing the string. When you have magic quotes on it's sort of like doing `mysql_real_escape_string` twice, making the variable in your query `<a href=\\"http://foo.com\\">foo</a>`. This is why magic_quotes is deprecated and should be turned off. This is unsafe and leaves you open to attack.

To answer your question, with magic quotes off and using `mysql_real_escape_string` you are safe from SQL injection

Comment: Your answer made me understand the way it works. Magic_quotes was my problem then. Thank you for answering my general question, "am I safe"?